# add tags dynamically on Tab and Spacebar event in ngx-chips

Tags: angular, ngx-chips

**Please Anyone tell me how add tags dynamically on Tab and Spacebar event in ngx-chips.**

[image: ngx-chips]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **separatorKeyCodes** (number[]) or **separatorKeys** (string[])

```
 <div class="force-to-the-bottom">
  <tag-input [ngModel]="['hardocoded-item']" [separatorKeyCodes]="[32,9]">
  <tag-input-dropdown
    [autocompleteItems]="items"
    [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true"
    [dynamicUpdate]="false">
 </tag-input-dropdown>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-chips-example-miqu3i?file=app%2Fshared%2Ftag-input%2Ftag-input.component.html